# Remapping left CTRL, left ALT and left Win key without SharpKeys and rewriting registries? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

I am used to working on Mac and I've always remapped my Windows machines with SharpKeys but unfortunately my new employer doesn't allow me to use it.

My goal is to change `L CTRL` to `L WIN`, `L WIN` to `L ALT` and `L ALT` to `L CTRL`. Is there a way to do it without SharpKeys?

I've also read about registry change but I am pretty confused about it and not sure exactly how to write it for my solution and I am also waiting for approval from my IT team.

Also, is there any third way of how to change keybinds?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1539085/is-there-a-way-of-mapping-a-key-combination-of-a-computer-type-a-character/1539125#1539125

Comment: Think different: Remap the keys on your mac to the proper way and get used to it.

Comment: What a pity that we cannot downvote some comments.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot. But SharpKeys is a really useful utility that avoids you to manually change the registry keys, once for all.

And, it is really useful in emulating MacOS position for Ctrl/Command keys.

You only have to run it once, for the registry edit, then reboot… You may then safely remove the software from your Windows (and store it in the “toolbox” attic).

The only remaining problem will be, in MacOS, when you will start a terminal and strike ⌘-C instead of Ctrl-C :)

Comment: I will beg my IT team to install SharpKeys as I've already used it several times, I hope they will let me have it :)

Comment: SharpKeys is (also) a portable application :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get IT approval, you can use this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,38,00,1d,00,5b,e0,1d,\
  00,38,00,5b,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Which was created with this **PowerShell Code** that creates the reg value for what ever scancode pairs specifed.

### Must be run from Admin PowerShell

```
##############################################################
$SimplePairs = @(
 0x38, 0x1d # lAlt > lCtrl
)

$ExtendedPairs = @(
 0x5b, 0xe0, 0x1d, 0x00 # LWinKey(0xe05b) > L Ctrl(0x1d)
 0x38, 0x00, 0x5b, 0xe0 # L Alt(0x38)     > LWinKey(0xe05b)
)
$ByteCount = 2 * $SimplePairs.Length + $ExtendedPairs.Length + 16
$Remap = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList $ByteCount
$Remap.Length
$Remap[8] = $SimplePairs.Length/2 + $ExtendedPairs.Length/4 + 1
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $SimplePairs.Length ; $i += 2) {
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 12] = $SimplePairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i * 2 + 14] = $SimplePairs[$i + 1]
}
For ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $ExtendedPairs.Length ; $i += 4) {
   $Offset = $SimplePairs.Length * 2
   $Remap[$i + 12 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i]
   $Remap[$i + 13 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 1]
   $Remap[$i + 14 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 2]
   $Remap[$i + 15 + $Offset] = $ExtendedPairs[$i + 3]
}
$Splat = @{
Path  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
Name  = 'ScanCode Map'
Value = $Remap
Force = $True
}
$Splat['Value'] | format-hex
New-ItemProperty @Splat
```