# F2 key on my keyboard is getting triggered automatically. How to disable it?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys, rename

I'm using Asus gl502vt laptop, since last two months I'm facing an issue with the <kbd>F2</kbd> key. It's getting auto pressed randomly out of no where. I tried reinstalling the OS/drivers, but nothing helped. It's a laptop and during this pandemic time I don't have many options to fix this at hardware level.

<kbd>F2</kbd> is the shortcut for getting into BIOS setup in Windows, and 7/10 times, my PC goes into BIOS setup during boot on its own.

Can you help me here by disabling the key or at least its functionality like rename a file? On many applications this was causing side-effects.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1539085/is-there-a-way-of-mapping-a-key-combination-of-a-computer-type-a-character/1539125#1539125 so `00,00,3C,00,`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is facing this issue, I used below software to disable it. it is legit and also my antivirus detected nothing.

https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys

Answer (score 0):

Clean the keyboard! This problem is often simply due to dust or crumbs causing a key to stay partially down and make intermittent contact.

Unplug the keyboard (or for an integrated keyboard in a laptop etc, apply to whole machine), then turn it over and carefully tap the edge on your desk.

Still with the keyboard inverted, run your hand back and forth so the keys are pressed in and spring out again. This will dislodge any debris so that it falls out from between the keys, allowing them to regain their full travel.

The "flipping" action is the key thing (pun intended!). Make sure you press each key fully and get it to spring out hard a number of times, and watch out for any keys sticking that need extra work to rid them of hidden debris and restore full freedom of travel.

Comment: Hey @reg-edit 
Thanks for the response. It is a laptop keyboard, not any external keyboard. I cleaned it up and also well maintained.So, I disabled the button using sharp keys software. Link: https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases

Comment: @RahulKodumuru glad you got it solved. I've updated my answer to make clear that this is good for laptops too for others in the future.