# Is it possible to map a key combination to other key

Tags: windows-10

In my Windows 10 laptop 1 key is not working which is "9 (" as a CS student I use "(" very frequently. Since only one key  is not working I don't want to spend money on replacement. External keyboard is not possible for me use every where.
So is there any way to map key combination to "(". Like alt+c="("

Comment: If you download AutoHotkey, you'll quickly be able to make any such mapping.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1539085/is-there-a-way-of-mapping-a-key-combination-of-a-computer-type-a-character/1539125#1539125. So `0a,00,43,00`.